# What beer does the lumberjack want?

Tags: fiz

The lumberjack wants me to give him some beer that reminds him of the earth.  What beer is that?

Comment: Incidentally, since you skipped it the first time around, the Lumberjack bar is *far and away* the best early-mid game moneymaker. An overwhelming majority of customers want IPA ONLY, but your competitors are often too stupid to sell IPA, which means you can mark a batch up to 25-30/each and sell out every time for a tidy profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pair of Irish Red Ales with an "earthy" flavor. Either Red Kastle or Red Keep should work fine.